# Article usage in “with + (a/an) + adjective + noun”

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

What is the best formulation, and eventually what are the differences, between:

1. This task can be done without **a** human annotation.
2. This task can be done without    human annotation.

Comment: This is essentially asking about the differences between count nouns and non-count nouns (a cold; flu). The rest is non-germane (a boy with a cold; a boy with flu // a boy with a severe cold; a boy with severe flu).

Comment: Could you provide the full context?

Comment: Something like : "This task can be done without ... ". I edited the question.

Comment: There's no "best" without context. (Btw, there can be no "best" between **two** alternatives, in any case!) Both are eminently valid, sensible and useful. What's the Q now?

Comment: It's not "a" + adjective, it's really (indefinite article)+(compound noun/ noun phrase/ noun clause). Look at it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*2. The **process** of human annotation is not necessary for completing this task.*

*1. Not even a **single instance of an event of this process** is necessary for completing it.*

The **process** is comprised by many individual **/events/acts/instances/** of human annotation.